# What is the use of these characters \u000d\u000a and &#xA;

Tags: xml

What is the use of these characters \u000d\u000a and `&#xA;` in a XML string ? i am seeing these characters as part of a payload which i need to  post for a REST api.

Answer (score 1):

`&#xa;` is recognised by the XML parser as a newline character. In most contexts (but not all, for example within CDATA) it's the same as having a literal newline in your XML.

`\u000d\u000a` has no special meaning in XML, but it might mean something to the sending or receiving application. As far as XML is concerned it's just a sequence of 12 ordinary characters, but to the application it might be a representation of the two characters CR LF, used to represent a line ending on Windows systems.

Comment: It might be worth adding that both representations refer to the representation of "new line" in ASCII, 0001010, which is decimal 10 or hexadecimal A (and "carriage return" is 0001101 = 13 = D)